# How can I pub/sub remote event through more than one topic with Spring Cloud Bus

Tags: events, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-bus

I'm using Spring Cloud Bus to exchange event among micro-services.

By default, it seems that one app(micro-service) ONLY CAN figure one topic.

spring:
cloud:
bus:
id: xxx
destination: my-topic
kafka: 127.0.0.1:9092

Is there any way to config more than one 'destination'(topic) in Spring Cloud Bus? And then I can pub/sub different event through different topics.

e.g. CustomerEvent through topic named customer, while AccountEvent through topic named account.

I'm working with Spring Cloud Bus 2.2.4.RELEASE.

Thanks very much for helping on this issue.